What is the name of this martial arts asian movie in which the protagonist journeys to complete his training but dies?
The movie is most likely from Thailand. I watched It around a year ago, so probably it was released around this period. 
Plot: 
The protagonist-a teenager- after mastering martial arts from his father, 
he sends him on a journey to gain wisdom.Just like his older brother did.
So he sets off and meets with a teenage girl and her younger brother.
The girl was about to be taken by a local gang to be sold to a woman trading 
international ones, so he saves her but she is taken later and get raped, 
and he goes to save her again and succeeds but receives a fatal injury and 
die.
The girl takes her brother and goes to his hometown and lives with his family.  
Some scenes I remember: 
1- This was early in the movie, the protagonist's father was fighting  him to see how far he progressed.  
2- While on the run, the protagonist, the girl and her brother spend the night in large tubes in a construction site.  
3-  During the chase, the little brother is hidden by most likely the protagonist, who promises him that he'll return back.This chase happened when they were trying to get some stuff from their house.

This is pretty much the plot of Merantau from 2009. It's Indonesian, though.

In Minangkabau, West Sumatera, Yuda a skilled practitioner of Silat Harimau is in the final preparations to begin his "Merantau" a century's old rites-of-passage to be carried out by the community's young men that will see him leave the comforts of his idyllic farming village and make a name for himself in the bustling city of Jakarta. After a series of setbacks leave Yuda homeless and uncertain about his new future, a chance encounter results in him defending the orphaned Astri from becoming the latest victim of a European human trafficking ring led by the wildly psychotic, Ratger and his right-hand man Lars. With Ratger injured in the mêlée and seeking both his "merchandise" and bloody retribution, Yuda's introduction to this bustling city is a baptism of fire as he is forced to go on the run with Astri and her younger brother Adit as all the pimps and gangsters that inhabit the night hound the streets chasing their every step. With escape seemingly beyond their grasp, Yuda has no choice but to face his attackers in an adrenaline charged, jaw-dropping finale.

Everything you described (including the end) is Yuda's attempts to protect Astri and her kid brother. The martial arts technique is pencak silat. Posted a similar answer here but it was never confirmed. Here's the trailer:



